# SQL Server How to properly create a view upon dependent tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance, sqlperformance

Given the following tables (see below) I need to create a View that shows each code (SOC, HLGT, HLT, PT AND LLT) from table `MedDRARelations` and his respective value (Soc_Value, HLGT_value, HLT_Value, PT_Value and LLT_Value) from the table `MedDRANames`.

I've tried by joining multiple times the `MedDRANames` table and creating a scalar function which returns value given the code (key).

Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MedDRANames 
(
    [Key]   INT NOT NULL,
    [Value] VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MedDRANames] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Key])
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.MedDRARelations 
(
    [SOC]  INT NOT NULL,
    [HLGT] INT NOT NULL,
    [HLT]  INT NOT NULL,
    [PT]   INT NOT NULL,
    [LLT]  INT NOT NULL,    
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MedDRARelations] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SOC] ASC, [HLGT] ASC, [HLT] ASC, [PT] ASC, [LLT] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_MedDRANameSOC] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([SOC]) REFERENCES dbo.MedDRANAmes([Key]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_MedDRANameHLGT] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([HLGT]) REFERENCES dbo.MedDRANAmes([Key]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_MedDRANameHLT] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([HLT]) REFERENCES dbo.MedDRANAmes([Key]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_MedDRANamePT] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([PT]) REFERENCES dbo.MedDRANAmes([Key]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_MedDRANameLLT] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([LLT]) REFERENCES dbo.MedDRANAmes([Key])
);
```

Views:

This view executes in 22.1 s (SD 1.25) and affects 156867 rows

```
SELECT 
    [X].[SOC] AS [Código SOC],
    [SOC].[Value] AS [Término SOC],
    [X].[HLGT] AS [Código HLGT],
    [HLGT].[Value] AS [Término HLGT],
    [X].[HLT] AS [Código HLT],
    [HLT].[Value] AS [Término HLT],
    [X].[PT] AS [Código PT],
    [PT].[Value] AS [Término PT],
    [X].[LLT] AS [Código LLT],
    [LLT].[Value] AS [Término LLT]
FROM 
    dbo.MedDRARelations AS [X]
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.MedDRANames AS [SOC] ON [X].[SOC] = [SOC].[Key]
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.MedDRANames AS [HLGT] ON [X].[HLGT] = [HLGT].[Key]
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.MedDRANames AS [HLT] ON [X].[HLT] = [HLT].[Key]
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.MedDRANames AS [PT] ON [X].[PT] = [PT].[Key]
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.MedDRANames AS [LLT] ON [X].[LLT] = [LLT].[Key]
```

This view executes in 35.3 s (SD 2.1) and affects 156867 rows

```
SELECT 
    [X].[SOC] AS [Código SOC],
    dbo.FindMedDRA(x.SOC) AS [Término SOC],
    [X].[HLGT] AS [Código HLGT],
    dbo.FindMedDRA(x.HLGT) AS [Término HLGT],
    [X].[HLT] AS [Código HLT],
    dbo.FindMedDRA(x.HLT) AS [Término HLT],
    [X].[PT] AS [Código PT],
    dbo.FindMedDRA(x.PT) AS [Término PT],
    [X].[LLT] AS [Código LLT],
    dbo.FindMedDRA(x.LLT) AS [Término LLT]
FROM 
    dbo.MedDRARelations AS [X]
```

Scalar functions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FindMedDRA]
    (@code INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returning VARCHAR(100)

    SELECT @returning = dbo.MedDRANames.Value 
    FROM dbo.MedDRANames 
    WHERE dbo.MedDRANames.[Key] = @code

    RETURN @returning
END
```

I would like to know what is the proper way to achieve this because creating a joined table elapses 12.2 s (SD 0.1) but costs 5 times original space.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE: Execution plans**

1. Using function:  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkso0aKnV
2. Before Ixs creations:  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkFlyRth4
3. After Ixs creations (as suggested by Laughing Vergil): https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B13ZW0t3V

Comment: Are you worried about code length? That's unimportant when trying to achieve the right way. Each instance of `MedDRANames` represents a different entity and should be called independently. Using user-defined scalar functions is a performance problem and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Can you share the execution plan? Go to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and paste in the XML version of the execution plan

Comment: @LaughingVergil the execution plan won't show an accurate cost when using UDFs.

Comment: Yes, but it will when you show the view version only, without the function.

Comment: You cannot **execute** a view - you create a view by defining its tables and joins, and then you **select from** a view. Is that what you mean? Selecting all rows from the view takes 22.1 vs 35.3 seconds....

Comment: The Execution Plan is generated whenever a query is executed. In the case of a view, you can either execute the code within the view separately, or `SELECT` from the view. Either way, you can view the execution plan. To do this, go into SQL Server Management Studio, set up your query, click on the Query menu option, and select **Display Estimated Execution Plan**. Right click on the plan, and select **Show Execution Plan XML...**. Copy the XML, and paste it into PasteThePlan as mentioned above.

Comment: Alternately, you can click on **Show Actual Execution Plan**, then run the query. After the execution plan is shown, perform the same steps as in the previous query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest issue here is that there is no index on the values in `MedRARelations`. NOTE: A common misconception is that creating a Foreign Key creates an index. It does not.

So, try running this:

```
CREATE INDEX Idx_MedDRARelations_SOC ON MedDRARelations (SOC);
CREATE INDEX Idx_MedDRARelations_HGLT ON MedDRARelations (HGLT);
CREATE INDEX Idx_MedDRARelations_HLT ON MedDRARelations (HLT);
CREATE INDEX Idx_MedDRARelations_PT ON MedDRARelations (PT);
CREATE INDEX Idx_MedDRARelations_LLT ON MedDRARelations (LLT);
```

Then try your view and other methods again.

Comment: Since the table `MedDRARelations` is only called once, only one index can be used. And since there's no WHERE clause, it will most likely do a table/clustered index scan.

Answer (score 0):

The first way is the correct one. `INNER JOIN`s on single column integer primary key is very fast, usually executed through `MERGE JOIN` operator. Certainly faster than making a function, as your results well show.